# Connecting to Azure Warehouse Mobile Management with Warehousing App

Tags: azure, configuration, dax, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I was giving the task to configure and test how the Warehouse Mobile Management works for Azure.

Setup:
I have found the [Warehousing App](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-warehousing/9p1bffd5tstm), and set it up with the help of [this video](https://organicax.com/2017/03/30/d365-warehouse-app-configuration-settings/).

Our current setup:
We have a Dynamics Finance and Operations Web App(DFO). So I created an app on Azure with the link pointing to the DFO App.
I am using `https://login.windows.net/microsoft.com` as the Active Directory Tenant.

Problem:
When I input the connection details, I get the error: `AADSTS70001: Application with identifier <App ID guid> not found in the directory microsoft.com`

Note:
I am relatively new to the whole Azure MS365 topic and unsure if there is something else that has to be done first which isn't obvious to me.
I have searched the web as much as I could.
I could not find any information from Microsoft or their documentation. But from my experience most of the time, the documentation I find from MS is outdated, so that doesn't help much.

I did find some document saying an on-premise installation hat to be done, but that statement turned out to be older than the documentation itself.

Comment: As I suspected, the AAD Tenant was the issue. Since it does not show where or how to get it in the video, I was using the wrong URL.


To get the right AAD Tenant, log into Azure365 and navigate to **[App registrations ] > [ Endpoints ]**.  There you'll see a list of Endpoints. 


For my case, using with the `Warehousing` app, I used the **OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT**


Other than that, the video on the blog post explains everything to the details.